# Retrieve data as array in Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Wordpress suppose I have 2 posts under category 'A'. Now I want to retrieve those posts of 'A' category as an array like below format

```
A=array(   
           [0] => Array([title]=>'abc'
                        ['description']=>'This is description A1' ),


           [1] => Array([title]=>'efg'
                        ['description']=>'This is description A2' ) 
)
```

So that I can display the values using `<?php echo A[0][title];?>`

I have already use `WP_Query()` but I can't get array wise data.

Is there any way to do that ? Anybody help Please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

I made up the query. This is just to show how to query.

```
$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts  WHERE (ID = %d  AND post_status = %s)", 15, 'static'), ARRAY_A  );
```

Comment: ...Let me try first please

Comment: It is very hard to debug this without more info. A few pointers: Check your errorlogs. Also tell wpdb to show errors with this command: $wpdb->show_errors();